# Cannot place a component in a router-outlet

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular5 and I am trying to use a router-outlet in my home page. What I'm trying to achieve is when you click on "Sample" link, the html of sample.component should be placed on where the router-outlet is. In my case, when I click on the "Sample" link it creates a separate sample page. With that, I think the routes.ts is working because it can find the html of the sample.component. It's just not placed on the router-outlet. If I can make this work, that means I can change the router-outlet with different component.html. Thank you.

**home.component.hml**

```
<div class="container">


<nav class="#37474f blue-grey darken-3">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a style="padding-left: 1em;" class="brand-logo ">
        <i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
        LOGO</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a (click)="Logout()">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/sample"  routerLinkActive='active'>Sample 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row" *ngIf="userClaims">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card #37474f blue-grey darken-3">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <span class="card-title">User Details</span><br>
          <span>Username: {{userClaims.UserName}}</span><br>
          <span>Full Name: {{userClaims.FirstName}} {{userClaims.LastName}}</span><br>
          <span>Email: {{userClaims.Email}}</span><br>
          <span>Is Active: {{userClaims.IsValid}}</span><br>
          <span>Log-in Time: {{userClaims.LoggedOn}}</span>

          <!-- <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          <a href="#">This is a link</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- container -->
```

**routes.ts**

```
import { SampleComponent } from './home/sample/sample.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { SignUpComponent } from './user/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './user/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    {
        path: 'signup', component: UserComponent,
        children: [{ path: '', component: SignUpComponent }]
    },
    {
        path: 'signin', component: UserComponent,
        children: [{ path: '', component: SignInComponent }]
    },
    { path: 'sample', component: SampleComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', redirectTo:'/signin', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

Comment: can you show the component where you created the `router-link`?

Comment: What do yout mean by saying "In my case, when I click on the Sample link it creates a separate sample page."? It is supposed to create a sample page.

Comment: Your AuthGuard, is there any code in there that might stop the route from occurring?

Comment: Provide plunker. Maybe there is something you are missing

Comment: @TomaszKula: In my case = What is happening in my current code...

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the routes.ts to this:

```
{ 
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{ 
    path: 'sample', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    children: [{ path: '', component: SampleComponent }]
},
{ 
    path: 'sample1', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    children: [{ path: '', component: Sample1Component }]
},
{
    path: 'signup', component: UserComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: SignUpComponent }]
},
{
    path: 'signin', component: UserComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: SignInComponent }]
},
{ path: '', redirectTo:'/signin', pathMatch: 'full'}
```